# Display hidden span next to checked radio button when submit button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a webpage with 25 Q's . And each has 4 options. When the user clicks on the button all glyphicon-ok should be displayed and glyphicon-remove next to checked radio buttons should be displayed. How to do it.

What should i add in below function.

```
$("#sub").click(function(){

});
```

I tried using CSS

```
/*
.glyphicon-remove
{
display: none;
}

input:checked + span{
display: block;
}
*/
```

My Html:

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="usr">Q25: A small bullet can kill a man if its momentum is great, a heavy truck moving a small  speed can kill a man easily sue to it momentum.-> Is as per which law of motion  </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" value="-0.33" name="optradio25">first<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" value="1" name="optradio25"> second <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" value="-0.33" name="optradio25">third<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" value="-0.33" name="optradio25">none<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></label>
    </div>
    <br />
    <table class="table table-hover" style="width: 100%;border: 0px">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <button id="sub" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <td align="right">
                    <button id="reset" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Reset</button>
                </td>

            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</form>
```

Comment: the CSS part displays span immediately after radio button is selected. i dont want that

Comment: Then what do you want? Display it after a delay? Fade in?

Comment: Just wanted to clarify, so what you want is when you click the submit button, you want to show the `span` element which has a class of `.glyphicon-ok` and `.glyphicon-remove`?

Comment: @prtdomingo is correct. No animations

Comment: @UPSCFever okay, I've added my answer below using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.next()` method of jQuery to add a class that will show the span of the selected radio button

```js
$("#sub").click(function(){
  $('input[type="radio"]:checked').next('span').addClass('show');
});
```

```css
.show {
  display: inline-block !important;  
}

span {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="usr">Q25: A small bullet can kill a man if its momentum is great, a heavy truck moving a small  speed can kill a man easily sue to it momentum.-> Is as per which law of motion  </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" value="-0.33" name="optradio25">first <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove">icon</span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" value="1" name="optradio25"> second <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok">icon2</span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" value="-0.33" name="optradio25">third<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" value="-0.33" name="optradio25">none<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></label>
    </div>
    <br />
    <table class="table table-hover" style="width: 100%;border: 0px">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <button id="sub" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <td align="right">
                    <button id="reset" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Reset</button>
                </td>

            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</form>
```

Comment: hi your solution will display all glyphicon-remove. Even those that are not next to radio buttons that are selected. But your code for glyphicon-ok is working fine.

Comment: this isnt solving the problem. how to display glyphicon-remove next to checked radio buttons when the submit button is clicked.

Comment: @UPSCFever I've updated my answer. See if this will work

Comment: This will basically select the span of the selected radio button. You can just add your logic from there to see if the answer is correct or not. If the answer is wrong, then show the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to wait 500 ms and then fade the span in slowly. I inserted a text in the span for demonstration reasons.

```js
$("#sub").click(function(){
  $(".glyphicon-remove").delay(500).fadeIn("slow");
  $(".glyphicon-ok").delay(500).fadeIn("slow");
});
```

```css
.glyphicon-remove
{
display: none;
}

.glyphicon-ok
{
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="usr">Q25: A small bullet can kill a man if its momentum is great, a heavy truck moving a small  speed can kill a man easily sue to it momentum.-> Is as per which law of motion  </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" value="-0.33" name="optradio25">first <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove">icon</span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" value="1" name="optradio25"> second <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok">icon2</span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" value="-0.33" name="optradio25">third<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" value="-0.33" name="optradio25">none<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></label>
    </div>
    <br />
    <table class="table table-hover" style="width: 100%;border: 0px">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <button id="sub" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <td align="right">
                    <button id="reset" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Reset</button>
                </td>

            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</form>
```